# ASP.NET 5 web application as Azure Web Role?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-sdk-.net, .net-4.6

We have a ASP.NET 5 web application in our solution.

Typically, we could right click on the Cloud Service "Roles" item and add a new role from an existing project in the solution.

But it cannot identity this project as a Web Role:

[image: Add Web Role Project in solution...]

How are we able to host a ASP.NET 5 project in a Azure Web Role?

**Edit:** We are using Azure SDK 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, we don't support WebRoles at the moment. You might* be able to hack your way around but officially there is no support. That means that any hack you do, will be in a text editor, not from tooling.

However, you can use an Azure WebSite instead. That's fully supported.

* it might not work at all. I am not aware of anyone who did this.

Comment: Would love to know if anyone does get this working. I gave it a half hour and decided to sanity check here with SO. Given that even for .NET 4.6 and guest OS family 4 you have to manually install netfx 4.6, I think it'll take some future work to get there.

Comment: Are there plans to support this in the future?

Comment: I cannot use a WebSite (now WebApp) right now as I have some legacy COM objects I need to register for some older code and I can only do this with a Cloud Service ... but I want to use the latest asp.net rather than re-code it again later on ... as Ender asked, will WebRoles ever be supported?

Comment: This is really frustrating. We can't use Web Apps because they can only be internet facing (except via web.config whitelisting - not good enough). And we can't use Web Roles because they don't support Asp.Net 5. So either we ditch Azure or ditch Asp.Net 5.

Comment: This is terrible. Can't use asp.net core with azure storage emulator. Hacking around with CSpack, CSrun doesn't work. When will asp.net core be supported for web roles?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to build your package yourself using [CSPack](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-model-and-package/). Here an example using PowerShell and CSPack:

```
# path to cspack
$cspackPath = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles 'Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.7\bin\cspack.exe'

$PackagePath = 'c:\mycloudpackage.cspkg'
$serviceDefinitionFile = 'c:\myProject\ServiceDefinition.csdef'
$webRoleName = 'MyWebRole'
$webRolePath = 'c:\myProject'
$webRoleEntryPoint = 'MyWebRole.dll'

# define the cspack parameters
$cspackParameter = @(
        "/out:$PackagePath",
        $serviceDefinitionFile,
        "/role:$webRoleName;$webRolePath;$webRoleEntryPoint",
        "/sites:$webRoleName;Web;$webRolePath"
    )

# execute cspack
& $cspackExe @cspackParameter
```

It also allows you to host multiple sites on a single web role.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't point to anything in particular. Could you please provide a bit more information or update the link?

Comment: I think the script doesn't need more explanation. However, I updated the link.

Comment: I'm following this script without the `$webRoleEntryPoint` and I keep getting the error `CloudServices077: Need to specify the pshyical directory for the virtual path Web/ of role webrole1`. I am pointing it to the azure cloud directory that holds `ServiceDefinition.csdef`.

Comment: I firgured it out, I was missing: `physicalDirectory="../SoundVast"` in .csdef file. `$webRoleEntryPoint` can be left out, it's only required for worker roles.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Cannot be done with Azure Storage Emulator...

I really struggled with this as I found the documentation seriously poor with no proper examples, so here's a full example of my scripts and files for anyone else, based on Martin Brandl's answer.
You do not need `webRoleEntryPoint` for only a web role. Only used for worker roles.

- Create a new empty cloud service in your project. This will generate empty`ServiceConfigiguration.Cloud.csfg`, `ServiceConfigiguration.Cloud.csfg` and `ServiceDefinition.csdef` files for you as well as an empty roles folder. You could also add a web/worker role to let visual studio generate the configuration in them and then just modify them accordingly.
- Modify these files (change the `physicalDirectory` to your own):

`ServiceDefinition.csdef`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SoundVast.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="../SoundVast">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

`<Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="../SoundVast">` is the important line, this `physicalDirectory` is relative to wherever your `.csdef` file is located and I wanted to make my main project `SoundVast` the web role which was located one level up.

`ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.csfg` and `ServiceConfiguration.Local.csfg` (both can be the same):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="SoundVast.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <Role name="WebRole1">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

The important part is that the role name matches your `<Role name="WebRole1">` service definition files web role name.

```
# path to cspack
$cspackPath = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles 'Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.8\bin\cspack.exe'

$PackagePath = 'C:\Users\Yamo\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SoundVast\SoundVast.Azure\SoundVast.cspkg'
$serviceDefinitionFile = 'C:\Users\Yamo\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SoundVast\SoundVast.Azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef'
$webRoleName = 'WebRole1'
$webRolePath = 'C:\Users\Yamo\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SoundVast\SoundVast.Azure'

# define the cspack parameters
$cspackParameter = @(
        $serviceDefinitionFile,
        "/role:$webRoleName;$webRolePath;",
        "/sites:$webRoleName;SoundVast;$webRolePath",
        "/out:$PackagePath"
    )

# execute cspack
& $cspackPath @cspackParameter
```

A `.cspkg` file should now have been generated at the location of your `$PackagePath`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just blogged on how to do this (with VS tooling support!) here: https://oren.codes/2017/10/16/using-asp-net-core-with-azure-cloud-services/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it isn't officially supported as a web role at this time. It seems that it is only compatible with the web apps and not the older web role. The current work around is documented on this site:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331425/Running-an-EXE-in-a-WebRole-on-Windows-Azure