# Error: Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path 'Web/' of role

Tags: powershell, azure, asp.net-core

I'm following the answer at the bottom of this question here: [ASP.NET 5 web application as Azure Web Role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669008/asp-net-5-web-application-as-azure-web-role/31784053#comment64519682_31784053) as I am trying to build an azure web role for asp.net core.

When I run the powershell script I get the error:

> Error CloudServices077: Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path 'Web/' of role

If anyone knows another way to use azure web roles in asp.net core then I am all for that too.

I'm using CSPack to try and configure this.

Powershell Script:

```
# path to cspack
$cspackPath = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles 'Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.8\bin\cspack.exe'

$PackagePath = 'I:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SoundVast\SoundVast.Azure\SoundVast.cspkg'
$serviceDefinitionFile = 'I:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SoundVast\SoundVast.Azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef'
$webRoleName = 'WebRole1'
$webRolePath = 'I:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SoundVast\SoundVast.Azure'

# define the cspack parameters
$cspackParameter = @(
        $serviceDefinitionFile,
        "/role:$webRoleName;$webRolePath;",
        "/sites:$webRoleName;SoundVast;$webRolePath",
        "/out:$PackagePath"
    )

# execute cspack
& $cspackPath @cspackParameter
```

ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SoundVast.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

ServiceConfiguration.Cloud & ServiceConfiguration.Local

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="SoundVast.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <Role name="WebRole1">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Folder structure (if it makes a difference...)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the phsycial directory on this line: `<Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="../SoundVast">`. After this I ran the script and it created a package for me. The documentation on this is really not good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SoundVast.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="../SoundVast">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and resolved it by deleting the web role from my cloud service (it was an MVC) and generating a new one. I had made so many modifications it had become messy, so  making a new one from scratch solved the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).